# Scatter() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I'm new to this and I'm trying to represent a structured array, npy file as a scatter plot. I'm not entirely sure what my other argument should be. I was thinking that I should span out my values for `x` and `y`, but I am not sure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

path = '/users/username/Desktop/untitled folder/python     files/MSII_phasespace/'

os.chdir( path )

data = np.load('msii_phasespace.npy',mmap_mode='r')

# data.size: 167197
# data.shape: (167197,)
# data.dtype: dtype([('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'),
  # ('velx', '<f4'), ('vely', '<f4'), ('velz', '<f4'), ('m200', '<f4')])

plt.title ("MS II data structure")
plt.xlabel(r'$\Omega_{\mu \nu}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\Omega^{\mu \nu}$')

plt.scatter(data)
plt.show()
```

Inputting this outputs the error:

> `TypeError: scatter() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: what exactly is unclear? A scatter plot always between two vectors. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: So a scatter plot cannot be made with this file?

Comment: Are you sure that you understood the concept of a scatter plot? You may want to google and look at the results. Is this what you actually want to plot here?

Comment: I have the information marked by #, its (167197,).

Comment: Well, a scatter plot requires x and y data. A (x,y) pair creates a point, and all pairs together constitute the scatter plot. If you only have data for one axis, you cannot do a scatter plot. Here is an example of a scatter plot: http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html

Comment: That's unfortunate. The data is from the Millennium-II simulation that contains data on every halo in the simulation at o redshift. Would this data only be usable for just plotting and function making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) there. Matplotlib does not know what to do with it. As given in the [documentation for `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) you need to specify two input arrays `x`, and `y`.

From the `dtype` output, I gather that your structured array has values for `'x'`, `'y'`, `'z'`, `'velx'`, `'vely'`, `'velz'`, and `'m200'`. I have no clue what they are, but in order to create a scatter plot, you need to specify two components, e.g.:

```
plt.scatter(data['x'], data['y'])
```

Assuming that `'m200'` should be mapped to the width of the scatter points, you could use:

```
plt.scatter(data['x'], data['y'], s=data['m200'])
```

Comment: Okay, it worked. I will do my to understand this more thoroughly. Thank you you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`plt.scatter` needs at least two arguments (which the error states quite clearly).

If you look into the docs (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter), you will see this signature:

```
scatter(x, y, s=20, c=None, marker='o', cmap=None, norm=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, verts=None, edgecolors=None, hold=None, data=None, **kwargs)
```

So you need to provide at least an array for each `x` and `y` values:

```
plt.scatter(data['x'], data['y'])
```

Starting from matplotlib 1.5, you could also use this syntax
to access data from a structured array:

```
plt.scatter('x', 'y', data=data)
```